# OpenID on Community Server

Tags: ssl, openid, community-server

Okay, I've asked on the Community Server Forums and was totally ignored. So I'll ask here. The OpenID provider (presumably janrain) for CommunityServer does not work with an SSL OpenID endpoint. I really don't know of a non SSL OpenID endpoint and even if I did...I'm not sure if I'd want to use it.

I have a community server installation and all of my users are complaining that the signup/login form appears to support openid but doesn't in reality. has anyone encountered this issue and addressed it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CS currently uses an old version of Janrain's C# library.  I think the next version is expected to use dotnetopenid.  But even in its current release I would expect it to work just fine with SSL OP endpoints.  If it didn't, then no OpenIDs from myopenid.com would work for logging into CS and I would expect the CS guys would have noticed that.

However, if specific endpoints are broken, it may be a sign of another problem. If you can give specific OpenID endpoints that are not working then please send an email to dotnetopenid@googlegroups.com and I'll be happy to investigate it further.

There's a test OP Endpoint that is non-SSL that you can try out to see if it works by logging into your CS with this: http://nerdbank.org/opaffirmative/affirmativeidentity.aspx (yes, that's actually a valid OpenID you can log in with without using a password).

Comment: The specific endpoint I'm having problems with is yahoo. But like I said, several users have expressed problems with connecting to the site through openid